# angularjs routeprovider variation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am quite new with angular, so I am not sure if what I want to do is actually achievable with angular or if it is better to use some other framework.

This is my situation, we have a website made in wordpress, that contains a bit more than 500 pages, all of the pages are the same (exact same content). The main reason they builded this way is:

1. availability to have custom "domain names", IE:
   www.page.com/mypage1
   www.page.com/mypage2
   www.page.com/mypage...
2. there is one section on the page that contains an iframe, the iframe is the same on all pages except for a parameter so for instance the iframe of mypage1 has as an url: www.otherpage.com?client=client1Id

So I have use angular before to do a very simple $routeProvider, so I am wondering if I can use the same concept but with some changes

```
var sampleLandingPage = angular.module('sampleLandingPage', []);
sampleLandingPage.controller('landingPage',['$scope', function ($scope){
$scope.pages = [
{
"FullName": "Client No 1",
"Name": "mypage1",
"CM": null,
"AF": "CLID001",
"OtherURL": null
},
{
"FullName": "Client No 2",
"Name": "mypage2",
"CM": "CLID002",
"AF": "CLID002",
"OtherURL": null
},
{
"FullName": "Client Special",
"Name": "mypage3",
"CM": "CLID002",
"AF": "CLID003",
"OtherURL": "/somethingelse"
}
];
}]);

sampleLandingPage.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
//$routeProvider.
}]);
```

so what I want to achieve is if the URL is requesting mypage2; to be able to display CM and AF in my page like {{ CM }} this way I can have only one page but on my iframe have the url like
www.otherpage.com?client={{ CM }}&otherparam={{ AF }}

and have a unique page that looks like

```
<body ng-app="sampleLandingPage">
<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="landingPage">
    page text...
    .........
    iframe ... url=www.otherpage.com?client={{ CM }}&otherparam={{ AF }}
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and finally if the OtherURL param is different to null, then display the actual URL define in this param

Comment: Are you familiar with how a `iframe` normally works, by setting it's `src`? Replace the url in the `src` with `www.otherpage.com?client={{ CM }}&otherparam={{ AF }}`.

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, I am not really sure if I understand your comment but I do, I dont understand also is how this will fix the problem? Thanks